# Чем посмотреть содержимое дампа полученного expdp Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть дамп выгруженный из БД Oracle. Как можно удобно посмотреть, какие объекты этот дамп содержит ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь параметром: `sqlfile`:

```
impdp directory=expdir dumpfile=myexp.dmp sqlfile=ddl.sql
```